# Как найти неизвестную папку в Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#

Вот у меня есть

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
  { "PATH", @"C:\Users\AdminST\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player\NativeCache\bcore-22.0.3497.01.2.12.0" },
}
```

Как мне проходясь циклом если на компьютере допустим изменилось `bcore-22.0.3497.01.2.12.0` изменилась версия (число) то оно его уже не найдёт.
Я хотел попробовать что-то типо добавить: `bcore-*.*` но как можно заставит через foreach искать что после *.* в `EnumerateFiles`

```
foreach (var spisok in data)
{
  foreach (var files in Directory.EnumerateFiles(spisok, "*.*")
  { 
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: А почему не использовать [Directory.GetFiles(String, String)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-6.0#system-io-directory-getfiles(system-string-system-string))? Если-же паттерн сложный, то может быть просто искать совпадение по паттерну-/ам всех поддиректорий?

Comment: @XelaNimed, EnumerateFiles используется для более быстрого перечисления

Comment: Вы можете хотя бы опубликовать код, который компилируется? Вы постоянно очень плохо реагируете на уточняющие вопросы в комментариях. На что вы рассчитываете? На то, что кто-то умеет читать ваши мысли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 2 метода:

1. Если версия всегда с одинаковым количеством цифр.
Для поиска по такому лёгкому паттерну подойдёт Directory.GetDirectories(путь, паттерн названия папки, метод поиска)

```
string path = "D:\\NativeCache";
string pattern = "bcore-*.*.*";
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path, pattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly); //SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly нужен для поиска папок только в поверхностной папке, что-бы случайно не словить папку из какой-нибудь под-папки.
```

Далее можно сделать проверку `dirs.Length > 0` и взять первую папку из массива. 

2. Если не важна версия и нужно найти по началу папки.

```
string path = "D:\\NativeCache";
string startWithPattern = "bcore-";
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
List<string> predictDirs = new List<string>();
foreach (string dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
{
    string dirName = dir.Split('\\')[^1];
    if (dirName.StartsWith(startWithPattern))
        predictDirs.Add(dir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, вам может помочь [File globbing in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/file-globbing).

Код может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Matcher matcher = new Matcher();
matcher.AddInclude("bcore-*");

var directoryPath = @"C:\Users\AdminST\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player\NativeCache";

foreach (var result in matcher.GetResultsInFullPath(directoryPath))
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Указываете шаблон поиска и путь к каталогу. Их можете брать из словаря.